# How to Count Number of Key : Values pair for given Key for JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

How to know `__metadata` and `ItemToEkbeNav` are root elements for its children (Key : Value) pair?

I tried many options `Object.keys().length`, `Array.isArray()`, but did not get the proper output.

For `Object.keys('__metadata').length = 10`, but I need it as 3 (`id`, `uri`, `type`).

For `Object.keys('Ebeln').length = 10`, but I need it as 1.

For `Object.keys('ItemToEkbeNav')` I want to know it's a root element for its children.

```
 "results": [
        {
            "__metadata": {
                "id": "https:// ,
                "uri": "https:// ,
                "type": "YGW"
            },
            "Ebeln": "5200000719",
            "Ebelp": "00010",
            "Loekz": "111",
            "Statu": "222",
            "ItemToEkbeNav": {
                "__deferred": {
                    "uri": "https: 
                }
            }
        }
  ]
```

Comment: `Object.keys('__metadata').length` is just telling you the **length of that string**, `'__metadata'.length`. The actual _object_ you're showing, wherever that's defined, is pretty clearly not involved _at all_ in that expression.

Comment: Object.keys(results[0]['__metadata'])

Comment: Where is your actual _code_? You're currently just showing a JSON string (an invalid one at that, it's missing the outer `{...}`), can you please show the code you're using to work with this data that's going wrong?

Comment: _"For `Object.keys('ItemToEkbeNav')` I want to know it's a root element for its children"_ - again your actual object isn't involved in the expression, and _"a root element for its children"_ as opposed to _what_, exactly?

Comment: You might find the function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#custom_method_that_gets_a_more_specific_type) useful to determine if an element is an object

Answer (score 0):

Well first off, your json is just wrong. Here's a usable format.

```
results = [
  {
    "__metadata": {
      "id": "https://",
      "uri": "https://",
      "type": "YGW"
    },
    "Ebeln": "5200000719",
    "Ebelp": "00010",
    "Loekz": "111",
    "Statu": "222",
    "ItemToEkbeNav": {
      "__deferred": {
        "uri": "https:"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

And then you would just fix it by doing
`Object.keys(results[0]["__metadata"]).length`

You will get a problem when you try to do it for `"Ebeln"` though, because the value you pass into `Object.keys()` will be a string.
The easiest way to handle this is probably different conditionals to handle determining how many keys there are based on if the value is an object, or a list, or any other data type.